# Use of jTDS to connect to SQL Server 2012 throws IOException; MS SQL Driver works

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jtds

The following code using jTDS driver (1.3.1):

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://anIpAddress;databaseName=aDatabase", "user", "pass")
```

results in:

```
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: DB server closed connection.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2481)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:632)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.crd.test.TestDb.main(TestDb.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DB server closed connection.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:852)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:731)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:114)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2368)
```

However, this code using MS SQL driver (4.2) works without exception:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://anIpAddress;databaseName=aDatabase", "user", "pass")
```

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database. Note: The user has read only access to the database. I do not have permission to change any configuration on SQL Server 2012. I have tried the same code to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database, and both the Microsoft and jTDS drivers work without exception in that case.

How can I connect to the SQL Server 2012 database without exception using jTDS?

Comment: Does "anIpAddress" really represent just an IP or does it in actuality represent a named instance on the server, like "someserver\instance"? It's possible that they have a non default instance listening on an odd port number, and the microsoft driver is correctly negotiating with the sql browser service to locate the listening port number for the instance, but the jtds driver is not. If that is the case, finding out the listening port number and explicitly putting it in the connection string should allow you to connect without the sql browser service.

Comment: "anIpAddress" represents an IP (e.g. 216.58.218.110). I can explicitly include the port number, 1433, using the MS SQL driver and it still works. If I explicitly include the port number using jTDS, it still fails.

Comment: I am facing the same issue while connecting to Azure DW microsoft sql server using jtds from sqoop and the cluster is kerberos enabled.. It would really help if someone replies as soon as possible...